# Can an I2C Eeprom have two addresses?

Tags: arduino, i2c

I own an [EEPROM module](https://robotdyn.com/eeprom-data-module-at24c256.html) with the [P24C256](http://www.puyasemi.com/uploadfiles/2018/08/201808062051475147.pdf) chip. (not AT24C256).

After scanning for available I2C devices, i got response from two devices.

```
Scanning...
I2C device found at address 0x50  !
I2C device found at address 0x58  !
done
```

I looked up the datasheet, but cannot find any additional information.
I thought that the device, has two banks for storage, but that does not seem to be the case.

How is this possible? After disconnecting the module, no I2C devices are reported.

```
#include <Wire.h>


void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);             // Leonardo: wait for serial monitor
  Serial.println("\nI2C Scanner");
}


void loop()
{
  byte error, address;
  int nDevices;

  Serial.println("Scanning...");

  nDevices = 0;
  for(address = 1; address < 127; address++ ) 
  {
    // The i2c_scanner uses the return value of
    // the Write.endTransmisstion to see if
    // a device did acknowledge to the address.
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    error = Wire.endTransmission();

    if (error == 0)
    {
      Serial.print("I2C device found at address 0x");
      if (address<16) 
        Serial.print("0");
      Serial.print(address,HEX);
      Serial.println("  !");

      nDevices++;
    }
    else if (error==4) 
    {
      Serial.print("Unknown error at address 0x");
      if (address<16) 
        Serial.print("0");
      Serial.println(address,HEX);
    }    
  }
  if (nDevices == 0)
    Serial.println("No I2C devices found\n");
  else
    Serial.println("done\n");

  delay(5000);           // wait 5 seconds for next scan
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your circuit? Also there is any other I2C device in your circuit?

Comment: @EsdrasXavier can you please check the update?

Comment: Try change the dip switch on the board, and see if the address change, maybe there is some problem with the chip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they can.

Depending on the size of the i2C EEPROM and how the memory blocks are organized you can have 2 or more device address. For example the ST24/25x04 EEPROM are 4 Kbit  electrically  erasable programmable memories,  organized as  2 blocks  of  256  x8  bits. That means that I2C gives you two device addresses (0x50 and 0x51 in the memory above), that will access each block with 1 byte address.

Comment: This case does not seem to apply on this eeprom. According to the datasheet the address is selected by 1|0|1|0|E2|E1|E0|R/W which goes from 1|0|1|0|000|R/W = 0x50H up to 1|0|1|0|111|R/W = 0x57H. (Not 0x58H). Generaly speaking you answered my question though. Thank you.

Comment: @OrElse, had you read the datasheet? It states 256 **K**bit, which means 256 * 1024 bits, or 256 * 8 * 128 (the latter is to have 7-bit addresses), so, it's exatly 8 pages starting from 0x50 till 0x57.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the problem with the EEPROM address bits, in case they are in floating state and not connected properly, Could you please check the connections on those address bits? Try to connect them to the same ground as your micro-controller, but yes, as advised above, schematics is highly needed.

Comment: Thank you David. The dip switches for selecting the I2C address seem to work perfectly. In fact when i change them both addresses change.

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is not implied to by. The datasheet says the address should be only one (but its three lower bits can be chosen).

The schematics for the boards shows only two bits (A0, A1) are selected by the dip-switch, and A2 is tied to the ground.

I see no initialization in the code. What frequency the TWI bus is working at? Also, in the pictures of the module it has jumpers to pull-up resistors unsoldered, and it has 10kOhm pull-up resistors even if jumpers are soldered - that may be too high.

Probably you have issue just because the wire is not returned to the high level fast enough.

1. Check pull-up resistors are engaged (jumpers are soldered on the board)
2. Try to add additional pull-ups (about 4.7k) on SCL, SDA
3. Try to set lower frequency, e.g. `Wire.setClock(50000);`